# Recyclerview is not loaded (it is just showing the empty screen)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I followed this video to show firebase-firestore data in my app.
But it is not loaded, showing empty screen.
I followed almost every code same except for the variables, and I don't know why it's not working. I checked the rules in firestore and it allowed read and write.
Here is my code, and I tried relocate the lines, set layout again... but doesn't work.
Please help me. (oh And there are no errors in running code)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private RecyclerView recyclerViewlist;
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    recyclerViewlist = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerViewlist.setHasFixedSize(true);

    init();
    getPostList();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerViewlist.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void init() {
    recyclerViewlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}

private void getPostList() {
    Query query = db.collection("post");

    //recyclerOptions
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Writeinfo> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Writeinfo>()
            .setQuery(query, Writeinfo.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Writeinfo, WriteinfoViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WriteinfoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_layout, parent, false);
            return new WriteinfoViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WriteinfoViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Writeinfo model) {
            Log.e("WOW", Integer.toString(position));
            holder.cvTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
            holder.cvContents.setText(model.getContents());
            //              holder.cvContents.setText(model.getContents());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    };
}

private static class WriteinfoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView cvTitle;
    public TextView cvContents;

    public WriteinfoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvTitle);
        cvContents = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvContents);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBwaJYocb9I

Comment: this is the video I followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your count method. it should be inside your adapter so that your RecylerView knows how many times it adds an item (view). it should not be zero

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListLength;
```